# Googlespread Sheet custom function #NUM! error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´ve made this custom function:

```
  function somaDias(range, days) {
     var soma = 0;

      for(i=0; i<days; i++){
          soma = soma + parseFloat(range[0][i])
      }

      return soma;
      }
```

I use it to sum the values from a range. The range is a Line in a sheet that has the budget for a given, one for each day of the month. I have to sum the values according to the day. I.e: if this the 14th, I need to sum the 14th first values.

So far so good. The function works. The problem is, if  the range has an empty cell, the returns #NUM!. I think I should put a if condition inside the for loop, but I don´t know how...

What should I do for this function work with empty cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simplified for of `IF THEN` like below

```
  function somaDias(range, days) {
    var soma = 0; 
    for(i=0; i<days; i++){
      soma += range[0][i]!=''? parseFloat(range[0][i]):0;
      }       
    return soma
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty cells can be checked like this:

```
function somaDias(range, days) {
  var soma = 0;

  for(i=0; i<days; i++){
    var v = range[0][i];
    if (v == "") {
      continue;
    }

    soma += parseFloat(v);
  }

  return soma;
}
```